# how can i get largest key from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, find, max

```
maxValue = int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[1])
for i in range(1, len(list(ab.keys()))):
    if maxValue > int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[1]):
        maxValue = int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[1])
sb = maxValue
maxValue = int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[0])
for i in range(1, len(list(ab.keys()))):
    if maxValue > int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[0]):
        maxValue = int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[0])
sa = maxValue
maxValue = int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[1])
for i in range(1, len(list(ab.keys()))):
    if maxValue < int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[1]):
        maxValue = int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[1])
bb = maxValue
maxValue = int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[0])
for i in range(1, len(list(ab.keys()))):
    if maxValue < int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[0]):
        maxValue = int(list(ab.keys())[i].split()[0])
ba = maxValue
```

i used to use this method, but i take too much time and i cannot use max(ab) cause my key look like this

```
ab = {"1 3":1, "2 3":2, "3 4":3}
```

Comment: How to make few lines of code unreadable...

Comment: @신호진 Are you looking for the maximal number in the keys (as stated that `maxValue` is a number) or the maximal key as a string?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need `max` with a custom key

**Ex:**

```
ab = {"1 3":1, "2 3":2, "3 4":3, "1 1": 4}
print(max(ab.items(), key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x[0].split()))))
```

**Output:**

```
('3 4', 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is your want to find largest key. So, if

```
ab = {"1 3":1, "2 3":2, "3 4":3}
```

then you are expecting "3 4" as the result. Is my understanding correct?

I am sharing a simplified conceptual program. See if this helps:

```
key_list = list(ab.keys())
key_list.sort()
print(key_list[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find largest key using,

```
max([i.replace(' ','') for i in ab.keys()])
```

If you need as `int`, use the following code.

```
max([int(i.replace(' ','')) for i in ab.keys()])
```

Comment: I think you don't need to use `replace` here

Answer (score 0):

Finding the maximal number in the keys (based on the original code posted in the question, where keys are split, and `maxValue` is a number):

```
import itertools

ab = {"1 3":1, "2 3":2, "3 4":3}

# Splitting keys to numbers
# [['1', '3'], ['2', '3'], ['3', '4']]
x = [k.split() for k in ab.keys()]

# Chaining together the lists of keys numbers
# ['1', '3', '2', '3', '3', '4']
y = list(itertools.chain(*x))

# Finiding max key
# 4
print(max([int(z) for z in y]))
```

One-liner:

```
# 4
print(max([int(z) for z in list(itertools.chain(*[k.split() for k in ab.keys()]))]))
```

Comment: 4 is not key. I guess he is expecting '3 4'

Comment: though he split it in 2 parts but key is '3 4' only.. Its a string

Comment: OP stated that `maxValue` as an int, not a string.